# BizTalk Application Version using VSTS

Tags: biztalk, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, biztalk-2016

I am using VSTS to build and deploy BizTalk 2016.
Do you know from where can I control Application's version number under Properties dialog?

[image]

The ideal would be to retrieve it from Version field in Visual Studio, but I could live without it.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend against incrementing the Assembly Version number for BizTalk deployments, unless you want to achieve side-by-side versioning https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308960(v=bts.10).aspx     It makes for a much more complex deployment process.  We prefer to increment the file version number

Comment: How about modify the version by using [Replace Token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task?

Comment: @starain-MSFT could you tell me in which file can I find the version number? that would be enough for me thanks for your help

Comment: Could you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: @starain-MSFT a bit difficult to share a project. I can live without it. thanks for your help.

Comment: You can refer to this article to share project https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-OneDrive-files-and-folders-9fcc2f7d-de0c-4cec-93b0-a82024800c07?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US